# Plotting previous data in pine script for Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

How can I have the previous data shown on Tradingview?  I've tried using the historical reference operator but it only shows the chart for the current time frame.

In Thinkorswim x[20] would plot x from 20 bars ago.  If I run this script in Thinkorswim after the market closes, it shows the previous 20 bars on the chart for the following trading day.  So it would show the graph from 6:30AM PST to 6:50AM PST the following day if using 1 minute data.

But in Tradingview it only shows up to the end of the trading day.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the `security()` function.

Comment: If 'previous data' you mean `previous trade`, then it's impossible. In tradingview a bar is only four series of open, high, low and close, so there's no previous value of the same bar. Many symbols have only one trade per a second though, so pretty often you can use seconds timeframe to look at the previous value. But amount of data in seconds resolution is short and it's only few last days.